# Is there an R function to split column from a txt file containing 20,000 columns by half so it can be used in excel

Tags: r, dplyr

I cannot open a txt data file as it is 8 gb size with around 20,000 columns so I want to separate the columns so I can use it as 2 files. I split the file using Gsplits but it splits only by rows. So if I open the split txt file in excel, it cannot load some data as it exceeds the number of column.

I tried using -contains() function as I wanted to remove some columns containing text TARGET. Even though the script is not showing any error codes, there is  no change in total number of columns.

```
df_sub <- select(disk1, -contains("TARGET-20-PANGDN-09"))
```

I want to remove all the variables starting with the text "TARGET-....", like the one shown above.

Comment: Try `-starts_with("TARGET-")`

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `{fst}` package: https://www.fstpackage.org/

Comment: Ya, that works @Phil